# The pointed Gromov-Hausdorff limit of action on manifold

Tags: metric-geometry, gromov-hausdorff-limit

The pointed Gromov - Hausdorff limit is a concept of the convergence of Riemannian manifolds :

For instance $$ (\lambda_i S^2(1) , p) \rightarrow_{G-H} ({\bf R}^2,O) = T_p S^2(1)$$ where 
 $\lambda_i \rightarrow \infty$. Here $ \lambda_i S^2(1) $ means the metric $\lambda_i g_0$ where $g_0$ is a canonical metric on $S^2(1)$.

Here I want to know the following question :

(a) What is the limit of ${\bf Z}_2=\pi_1({\bf RP}^2)$-action on $S^2$ ?

(b) And ${\bf Z}_p = \pi_1( L_p) $-action on $S^3$ ? Here $L_p$ is a lens.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) The antipodal action no the sphere is fixed-point-free and therefore does not preserve the distinguished point $p$ used in the construction of the G-H limit.  Hence the action does not descend to the G-H limit.

(b) The fundamental group of the Lens space similarly acts freely on the 3-sphere, so the action does not descend in this case, either.

Comment: Thank you for kind response. I have another question. Not a pointed G-H limit, in G-H limit what happen ? In my thought, in (a) it is still trivial. And for (b) consider the ${\bf Z}_p$ action on $T^2$ which may converges either ${\bf Z}^2$-action on ${\bf R}^2$ or ${\bf Z}$-action on ${\bf R}^2$. So in (b) the limit is ${\bf R}^3$, and the action is either
$$ {\bf Z} \ or\ {\bf Z}^2.$$ 
 Is this right ?

Comment: If you scale the metric, the limiting space will not be compact, so in this situation you can't work with G-H limit but rather you must work with the pointed limit to get a limiting space.  I don't think there will be an action in the limit unless the original action preserves the distinguished point.